# Why doesn't git clone pull down the description file?

Tags: git

I've been setting up cgit(an alternative to gitweb) and it pulls the description for a Repo from the description file. (`.git/description in a normal repo, and /description in a --bare`) But git seems to just ignore the file in a `git clone`(and `git clone --mirror`), meaning when you git clone the repo, the description file is the same as if you did a new git init.

Comment: Was the file commited to the repo?

Comment: @Antimony Files inside the .git directory aren't tracked, "committed to the repo" makes no sense here.

Comment: @meagar oops, I missed that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description file isn't a tracked part of the repository, and it doesn't come across during a clone. This is as designed. Its only purpose is to name the repo for [GitWeb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb).

Comment: @Rixius, to expand on this (correct) answer: Git exchange only operates on the so-called "refs" (references) which include: branches (named "heads" in the context of refs), tags and notes, -- that is, everything which, in a typical Git repo, lives under the "refs" subdirectory. That is all two Git instances are able to exchange.

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks it is stupid that `description` is not cloned. Cloning a repository or pushing it to a new server and loosing the `description` is non-sensical, as if GitWeb wouldn't want the description, and as if no other thing might want to know the project description!

Comment: @Jacob Put a README in the root of the project, and track it.